# Find the Thévenin equivalent circuit with the output terminals A and B

Tags: thevenin

Im not sure where to start with this question. I dont know what to do with the dependent source and im not sure what I can do with terminals A and B.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- To find \$R_{th}\$, connect a fictitious voltage source of 1V between A and B, so that \$V_x = 1\$

[image]

Now find I using KVL, 
$$-2 + 6 - 1- 2I = 0$$
which means, \$ I = 1.5 A \$

Therefore, the thevenins resistance \$R_{th}\$ seen from AB will be just \$ V_x/I = 1/1.5 = 0.667 ohms \$

- To find \$ V_{th}\$, look at the original ckt. It is the open circuit voltage across AB = \$V_x\$

[image]

\$V_x\$  should be equal to  \$-2V_x + 6\$  because current through 2 ohms = 0.

$$ V_x = -2V_x + 6 $$
$$\implies V_x = 2V  = V_{th} $$

- Now you can draw your thev.eq.ckt using \$ R_{th} = 0.667A \$ and \$ V_{th} = 2V \$

Comment: Why not choose a fictitious voltage source of 0V (short circuit across A and B)? That'd make it much easier. See my solution.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWEezg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You should start as usually by finding \$V_{TH}\$ voltage using any technique you know.

You should start as usually by finding \$V_{THE}\$ voltage using any technique you know.

\$V_{TH} = V_X+V1 = V_X+6V\$

So all we need is ti find \$V_X\$ voltage. So we can write a KVL equation:

$$V_2-I1*R_2+2V_{AB} = 0 $$

$$V_2-I1*R_2+2(V_X+V_1) = 0 $$

$$V_2-I1*R_2+2((V_2 - I_1R2)+V_1) = 0 $$

$$I = \frac{2V_1 + 3V_2}{3R_2} $$

And the Thévenin voltage is:

$$V_{TH} = V_2 - I_1 R_2 + V_1 = V_2 - \frac{2V_1 + 3V_2}{3R_2} R_2 + V_1 = \frac{V_1}{3} = 2V $$

Next we need to find the \$R_{TH}\$ resistance using this circuit diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8H83P.png)</sup>

As you can see I short A and B terminals. And I want to find this short circuit current \$I_{SC}\$

Additional notice that since we have a short across A-B terminal \$V_{TH} = 0V\$ hence \$V_X = 0A\$ So, the \$I_{SC}\$ current is:

$$I_{SC} = \frac{V_1}{R_1} = 3A$$

And the \$R_{TH}\$ resistance is

$$R_{TH} = \frac{V_{TH}}{I_{SC}} \approx 0.667 \Omega$$

And the equivalent circuit will look like this

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxsAQA.png)</sup>

Comment: It'd be nice if the downvoter would explain what he/she considers wrong with this answer?

Comment: Wonder why -1 ? O.o might be some personal vendetta going on.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to find the Thevenin equivalent.
Here is one that makes it particularyly easy to solve this problem:

Find **short circuit current** and find **open circuit voltage**:

<sup>Note: you can ignore completley the left subcircuit (4V voltage source and 6\$\Omega\$ resistor) as the voltage across its terminals is completely determined by the dependent voltage source and the dependent voltage source does not depend on any quantities of that left subcircuit.</sup>

**open circuit voltage** (i.e. \$i_X=0\$):

\$v_{oc} = -2v_X + 2\Omega \cdot i_X + 6V = -2v_{oc} + 6V\$ → \$v_{oc}=2V\$

**short circuit current** (i.e. \$v_X=0\$):

\$i_{sc} = \frac{6V - v_X}{2\Omega}  = \frac{6V - 0V}{2\Omega} = 3A\$

So you get
\$v_{Th} = v_{oc}\ = 2V\$ and
\$R_{Th}=\frac{v_{oc}}{i_{sc}}=\frac{2}{3}\Omega\$